# How to choose songs from my Rhythmbox library using Web Remote Control plugin?

Tags: music, rhythmbox, plugins, remote

Im using the Web Remote Control Plugin for Rhythmbox and it works. However its functionality is limited to showing album art, and previous, next and Play/Pause controls (see image).
[image]

Is there a way that this plugin (or another one) lets me see my library and choose a song from there remotely? I found [this one](https://blogs.gnome.org/jessevdk/2011/08/02/rhythmbox-webinterface-plugin/) but no luck on making it work because Im missing some dependencies I could not find.

I'm using Ubuntu Focal.

Comment: The this one you refer to appears to be quite old and may be for a much older version of Ubuntu. Since you never said what version of Ubuntu you are using that is just a guess.

Comment: Hi..it's Ubuntu Focal. Do you have a suggestion?